# C++: When and why is the destructor called?

Tags: c++, destructor, destroy

I have a simple program to test whether my cross product of two 3D-Vectors works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math\Vec3.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Vec3 v1(1, 23, 5);
    Vec3 v2(7, 3, 4);
    cout << "Crossing v1 and v2" << endl;
    Vec3 v3 = v1.cross(v2);
    cout << "crossed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why was the destructor called just after creating the variable? 
Here is what it printed out:

```
Created: Vec3[1, 23, 5]
Destroy: Vec3[1, 23, 5]     // Why is the vector destroyed here?
Created: Vec3[7, 3, 4]
Destroy: Vec3[7, 3, 4]      // And here?
Crossing v1 and v2
Created: Vec3[77, 31, -158]
Destroy: Vec3[77, 31, -158] //And here??
crossed
Destroy: Vec3[77, 31, -158]
Destroy: Vec3[7, 3, 4]
Destroy: Vec3[1, 23, 5]

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.090 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Here is the Vec3.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Vec3
{
    float x, y, z;

    Vec3():
        x(0), y(0), z(0) { std::cout << "Created: " << *this << std::endl; };
    Vec3(float i, float j, float k):
        x(i), y(j), z(k) { std::cout << "Created: " << *this << std::endl; };

    //...

    double dot(const Vec3&);
    Vec3 cross(const Vec3&);


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vec3);

    //...

    ~Vec3();
};
```

Vec.cpp:

```
Vec3 Vec3::cross(const Vec3& v)
{
    return Vec3(y * v.z - z * v.y,
                z * v.x - x * v.z,
                x * v.y - y * v.x);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vec3 v)
{
    out << "Vec3[" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << "]";
    return out;
}

Vec3::~Vec3()
{
    std::cout << "Destroy: "
        << "Vec3[" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << "]"
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not possible. Show us more code

Comment: please post the code for Vec3.h.

Comment: And possibly also for `Vec3.cpp`

Comment: BTW, the correct term is *destructor*, not deconstructor.

Comment: @NPE - nice catch, I didn't notice that. +1

Comment: O ... so this doesn't happen? .. its my code

Comment: It does not happen if the debug output inside Vec3 is implemented as everyone would think... hence the question for Vec3.cpp.

Comment: It would help to see the implementation of Vec3.

Also, I don't believe that "Destroy" print statements are happening when the destructor is called. The reason being that every object seems to be destroyed twice - one after the constructor, and one when it _should_ be at the end of the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your debug output (using `operator<<`) causes a copy (because it takes 'Vec3' by value) and an additional destruction.

You don't provide a copy constructor, so you can't see that. But if you would, you would see that you do in fact not have more destructions than constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output - you create a Vec3, then it gets destroyed, andf then right at the end the Vec3 gets destroyed... hmm, its obvious you have another Vec3 being created in the middle, and it is a copy of the Vec3 you wanted to create.

So that looks like the problem, you're confusing the output of Vec3s with a single object when something in your code is making a copy which in turn is destroyed. The reason this confusion happens is because you do not have a copy constructor defined that also prints out the 'created' line.

So, first adopt best-practice by adding a copy constructor to your code (hint: if you have 1 of constructor, destructor or copy-ctor, you should implement all 3. If you miss any out, the compiler will put one in for you).